# How to ensure a file is found in Java with FileReader?

Tags: java, algorithm, filewriter

I'm currently writing a DnD styled program for school, and i'm attempting to read out monsters and data about them from a text file. This is required to be done this way, so I elected to use FileReader. However, despite my best attempts, FileReader cannot find the path to the file, even after I attempt to create it if filereader can't find it.

I have tried placing copies of the required text file all throughout the directories that the program utilizes, however, I have yet to see any change.

I expect the filereader to find and establish a link to the file, however it fails to do so. I receive the error Java.io.FileNotFoundException. (I know I should be catching this in a try, will be done once I get this figured out)

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Main class variable declaration
        int menChoice;
        int numInElems = 3;
        int deaths = 0;
        String statRoll;
        Player player = new Player();
        Monster monster = new Monster();
        // Read in monster table
        /*File file = new File("monster_table");
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        if (!file.exists()) {
            createMonsterFile();
            System.err.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
        }
        try {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("monster_table.txt"));
            if (reader.readLine() != null) {
                System.out.println("Monster table successfully loaded.\n");
                clr();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("That's a pretty dank error mate.\nSeems as if you can't read your monster table\ninto your program, or create it.\n\nOuch.\n" + e);
        }*/
        // Begin user interaction
        System.out.println("Hello, welcome to the DnD program.\nPlease select and option to continue.\n1: Start\n2: Quit\n\n");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        menChoice = in.nextInt();
        System.out.println("\n");
        while (menChoice != 1 && menChoice != 2) {
            System.out.println("Invalid input. Please only enter 1 or 2.\n");
            menChoice = in.nextInt();
            System.out.println("\n");
        }
        if (menChoice == 1) {
            // If i had time i could like, be super cool and make a function for this, but that's for fuckin nerds lmfao
            System.out.println("Please pick a class.\n1. Barbarian\n2. Bard\n3. Druid\n4. Monk\n5. Paladin\n6. Rogue\n7. Warlock\n8. Wizard\n\n");
            String[] classes = {"Barbarian", "Bard", "Druid", "Monk", "Paladin", "Rogue", "Warlock", "Wizard"};
            menChoice = in.nextInt();
            while (menChoice < 1 || menChoice > 8) {
                System.out.println("Invalid input. Please only enter a valid choice.\n");
                menChoice = in.nextInt();
                System.out.println("\n");
            }
            player.setPlayerClass(classes[menChoice - 1]);
            System.out.println("Please pick a race.\n1. Dwarf\n2. Elf\n3. Gnome\n4. Halfling\n5. Human\n\n");
            String[] races = {"Dwarf", "Elf", "Gnome", "Halfling", "Human"};
            menChoice = in.nextInt();
            while (menChoice < 1 || menChoice > 5) {
                System.out.println("Invalid input. Please only enter a valid choice.\n");
                menChoice = in.nextInt();
                System.out.println("\n");
            }
            player.setRace(races[menChoice - 1]);
            System.out.println("Please pick a profession.\n1. Herbalist\n2. Alchemist\n3. Blacksmith\n4. Soldier\n5. Hunter\n6. Gambler\n\n");
            String[] professions = {"Herbalist", "Alchemist", "Blacksmith", "Soldier", "Hunter", "Gambler"};
            menChoice = in.nextInt();
            while (menChoice < 1 || menChoice > 6) {
                System.out.println("Invalid input. Please only enter a valid choice.\n");
                menChoice = in.nextInt();
                System.out.println("\n");
            }
            player.setProfession(professions[menChoice - 1]);
            // R A N D O M R O L L I N G  > * B E G I N ! *
            do {
                System.out.println("Rolling stats!");
                player.setSTR(ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(3, 18 + 1));
                player.setINT(ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(3, 18 + 1));
                player.setWIS(ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(3, 18 + 1));
                player.setCON(ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(3, 18 + 1));
                player.setDEX(ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(3, 18 + 1));
                player.setCHR(ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(3, 18 + 1));
                System.out.println("STR: " + player.getSTR() + "\n" + "INT: " + player.getINT() + "\n" + "WIS: " + player.getWIS() + "\n" + "CON: " + player.getCON() + "\n" + "DEX: " + player.getDEX() + "\n" + "CHR: " + player.getCHR() + "\n" + "Are you happy with this roll?\n(y/n)");
                statRoll = in.nextLine();
                while (!statRoll.equals("n") && !statRoll.equals("N") && !statRoll.equals("y") && !statRoll.equals("Y")) {
                    System.out.println("Invalid input. Please only respond with (y/n).\n");
                    statRoll = in.nextLine();
                    System.out.println("\n");
                }
            } while (statRoll.equals("n") || statRoll.equals("N"));
            System.out.println("\n");
            player.setHealth(player.getSTR() + 10);
            System.out.println("Your character has been created.\nIt is time to move forward to combat!\n\n");
            // Combat will begin here.
            while (player.getLevel() < 2) {
                File file = new File("./monster_table.txt");
                FileReader reader = new FileReader("./monster_table.txt");
                if (!file.exists()) {
                    createMonsterFile();
                    System.err.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
                }
                try {
                    if (reader.readLine() != null) {
                        System.out.println("Monster table successfully loaded.\n");
                        clr();
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    System.out.println("That's a pretty dank error mate.\nSeems as if you can't read your monster table\ninto your program, or create it.\n\nOuch.\n" + e);
                }
                player.setHealth(player.getSTR() + 10);
                if (deaths > 0) {
                    System.out.println("You awake in a nearby town, and on your way back to your party, you encounter another beast.");
                }
                int importNum = (int)(Math.floor(Math.random() * 11) + 1);
                if (importNum > 11) {
                    importNum = 11;
                } else if (importNum == 1) {
                    importNum = 2;
                }
                for (int i = 1; i < importNum; i++) {
                    reader.readLine();
                }
                String selectedMonster = reader.readLine();
                String[] monsterImport = selectedMonster.split(" ");
                if (monsterImport.length > numInElems) {
                    monsterImport[0] = (monsterImport[0] + " " + monsterImport[1]);
                    monsterImport[1] = monsterImport[2];
                    monsterImport[2] = monsterImport[3];
                    monster.setName(monsterImport[0]);
                    monster.setHealth(Integer.parseInt(monsterImport[1]));
                    monster.setDamage(Integer.parseInt(monsterImport[2]));
                }
                else {
                    monster.setName(monsterImport[0]);
                    monster.setHealth(Integer.parseInt(monsterImport[1]));
                    monster.setDamage(Integer.parseInt(monsterImport[2]));
                }
                while (player.getHealth() > 0 && monster.getHealth() > 0) {
                    System.out.println("You are at " + player.getHealth() + ". Your opponent, " + monster.getName() + ", is at " + monster.getHealth() + ".\nWhat will you do?\n1. Fight\n2. Run");
                    menChoice = in.nextInt();
                    while (menChoice != 1 && menChoice != 2) {
                        System.out.println("Invalid input. Please only enter 1 or 2.\n");
                        menChoice = in.nextInt();
                        System.out.println("\n");
                    }
                    if (menChoice == 1) {
                        int RNG = (int)Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
                        int monsterRNG = (int)Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
                        if (RNG == 1 || RNG == 2 || RNG == 3) {
                            monster.setHealth(monster.getHealth() - player.getDamage());
                            System.out.println("You dealt " + player.getDamage() + " damage to " + monster.getName() + "!");
                            if (monster.getHealth() <= 0) {
                                player.setExp(player.getExp() + 5);
                                if (player.getExp() > (player.getSTR() + 10) * 50) {
                                    player.setLevel(player.getLevel() + 1);
                                }
                            }
                        } else {
                            System.out.println("You missed!");
                        }
                        if (monsterRNG == 1) {
                            player.setHealth(player.getHealth() - monster.getDamage());
                            System.out.println("The monster dealt " + monster.getDamage() + " to you!");
                        } else {
                            System.out.println("The monster missed.");
                        }
                    } else {
                        int prayToRNGesus = (int)Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
                        if (prayToRNGesus == 1) {
                            monster.setHealth(0);
                            System.out.println("You have successfully fled.\n");
                        } else {
                            player.setHealth(0);
                            System.out.println("In your attempts to flee, you were slain.");
                            player.setExp(player.getExp() - 10);
                            deaths++;
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
            System.out.println("Congratulations on making it to level 2!\nDo you wish to save your character?\n1. Yes\n2. No");
            menChoice = in.nextInt();
            while (menChoice != 1 && menChoice != 2) {
                System.out.println("Invalid input. Please only enter 1 or 2.\n");
                menChoice = in.nextInt();
                System.out.println("\n");
            }
            if (menChoice == 1) {
                System.out.println("Excellent! Please name your character.");
                String name = in.nextLine();
                player.setName(name);
                System.out.println("Saving your character...");
                BufferedWriter writer;
                int i = 1;
                File outFile = new File("./character" + String.valueOf(i) + ".txt");
                while (outFile.exists() && i < 3) {
                    i++;
                    outFile = new File("./character" + String.valueOf(i) + ".txt");
                }
                try {
                    writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(outFile));
                    writer.write("Name: " + player.getName());
                    writer.newLine();
                    writer.write("Race: " + player.getRace());
                    writer.newLine();
                    writer.write("Profession: " + player.getProfession());
                    writer.newLine();
                    writer.write("Class: " + player.getPlayerClass());
                    writer.newLine();
                    writer.write("INT: " + String.valueOf(player.getINT()));
                    writer.newLine();
                    writer.write("STR: " + String.valueOf(player.getSTR()));
                    writer.newLine();
                    writer.write("WIS: " + String.valueOf(player.getWIS()));
                    writer.newLine();
                    writer.write("CON: " + String.valueOf(player.getCON()));
                    writer.newLine();
                    writer.write("DEX: " + String.valueOf(player.getDEX()));
                    writer.newLine();
                    writer.write("CHR: " + String.valueOf(player.getCHR()));
                    writer.newLine();
                    writer.flush();
                    writer.close();
                } catch(IOException e) {
                    System.out.println("IO error. " + e);
                }
            }

        } else if (menChoice == 2) {
            System.exit(0);
        } else {
            System.out.println("User input validation error.\n");
        }
    }

    private static void createMonsterFile() {
        File monsterFile = new File("./monster_table.txt");
        BufferedWriter writer;
        try {
            writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(monsterFile));
            writer.write("MonsterName HitPoints HitDamage\nHydra 50 6\nCyclops 20 1\nGiant Snake 5 1\nPhred 100 5\nPurple Monkey 10 2\nIce Golem 25 10\nHeat Miser 50 2\nSquirrel 2 5\nWhite Whale 80 4\nSmurf 5 2");
            writer.flush();
            System.out.println("Monster table successfully loaded.\n");
            clr();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("That's a pretty dank error mate.\nSeems as if you can't write your monster table.\n\nOuch.\n" + e);
        }
    }

    static void clr() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
            System.out.println("\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please read "How to create a [mcve]". Then use the [edit] link to improve your question (do not add more information via comments). Otherwise we are not able to answer your question and help you.

Comment: Meaning: separate your code. Dont put all things into if blocks. Write helper methods, like: `writeFile()` or so. Then you can *test* these methods separately, too. And you wouldnt need to copy/paste your whole huge program to us, but just that one method!

Answer (score 2):

It seems that your problem is due to naming the file differently when you are trying to read it than when you wrote it. The file name you are using when trying to read is **`"./monster_file"`**:

```
...
        file = new File("./monster_file");
        FileReader reader = new FileReader(file);
...
```

while the name of the file you actually wrote is **`"./monster_table.txt"`**:

```
...
        File file = new File("./monster_table.txt");
        if (!file.exists()) {
            createMonsterFile();
        }

...

    private static void createMonsterFile() {
        File monsterFile = new File("./monster_table.txt");
        BufferedWriter writer;
        try {
            writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(monsterFile));
...
```

[Complete code on GitHub](https://github.com/marco-ruiz/stackoverflow-qa/tree/master/so-common/src/main/java/so/a56143974)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks man, I realized that I left that in by mistake. I was attempting some debugging and messed that up, and then I forgot to take it out. Updated code is now in the original post, and the error that is now being thrown is that reader is never used.

Comment: Ok, that's a new problem, can you add this new stacktrace?

Comment: Also, I just notices that the new code will compile as is, since you are using `reader` in scopes where it doesn't exists (the 2nd try/catch block and half way through the code). Maybe declare the `FileReader` variable at the top of the method.

Comment: Ok, so I put the try blocks into the "combat" loop to force them to be within scope, and it recognizes reader now, however, it refuses to recognize readLine. I'll update code in a sec.

Comment: I upvoted you, don't know if it did anything since it flashed that it would be recorded but not visible since i'm a new account. But yeah, i'm having a difficult time understanding why it won't find the file, even when given a direct path to it.

Comment: It's hard to debug without stack traces; and your code, as it is, doesn't compile either. There's no `readLine` on `FileReader`; but there's on `BufferedReader `. See: http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-read-a-string-from-a-file-line-by-line.html?page=1

Answer (score 0):

The following instruction will look for the file in the current working directory.

`file = new File("./monster_file");`

The working directory depends on how you call your java application.

The best thing to do in such case is to emit some error message that clearly state what you are looking for and where, for example.

```
        File file = new File("./monster_file");
        if(!file.exists()){
            System.err.println("I can't find "+file.getAbsolutePath());
        }
```

Keep also in mind that you are looking for a file **without** extension, and maybe you instead have a file **with** extension. So you maybe are trying to open `monster_file` but in your directory you have `monster_file.txt`.

Comment: thanks, man. Oops, just realized i left a bit of debugging that wasn't even accurate in there. But i'll try this out and get back to you on it.